# Getting Time Difference

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to take the time difference getting from the dropdown lists. I have 3 dropdown list for representing Hour, Minute, AM/PM of Time in and Time out of an employee. My requirement is to calculate the working hours of the employee. Can i use Compare validator? if yes, how to use this?
my aspx code is shown below

```
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="middle">
            <asp:dropdownlist id="ddlTimeInHour" width="45px" runat="server" tabindex="7">
                <asp:ListItem>01</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>02</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>03</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>04</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>05</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>06</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>07</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>08</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>09</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>11</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>12</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:dropdownlist>
            <asp:dropdownlist id="ddlTimeInMinute" width="45px" runat="server" tabindex="8">
                <asp:ListItem>00</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>05</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>15</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>20</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>25</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>30</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>35</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>40</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>45</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>50</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>55</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>60</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:dropdownlist>
            <asp:dropdownlist id="ddlTimeInAMPM" width="45px" runat="server" tabindex="9">
                <asp:ListItem>AM</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>PM</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:dropdownlist>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="middle">
            <asp:dropdownlist id="ddlTimeOutHour" width="45px" runat="server" tabindex="10">
                <asp:ListItem>01</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>02</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>03</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>04</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>05</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>06</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>07</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>08</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>09</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>11</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>12</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:dropdownlist>
            <asp:dropdownlist id="ddlTimeOutMinute" width="45px" runat="server" tabindex="11">
                <asp:ListItem>00</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>05</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>15</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>20</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>25</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>30</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>35</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>40</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>45</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>50</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>55</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>60</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:dropdownlist>
            <asp:dropdownlist id="ddlTimeOutAMPM" width="45px" runat="server" tabindex="12">
                <asp:ListItem>AM</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>PM</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:dropdownlist>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Compare to what ? What's the start date, it is dynamic or static ? Please give us more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this:

```
string inTime = 
    String.Format("{0}:{1} {2}",
        ddlTimeInHour.Text,
        ddlTimeInMinute.Text, 
        ddlTimeInAMPM.Text);

string outTime =
    String.Format("{0}:{1} {2}",
        ddlTimeOutHour.Text,
        ddlTimeOutMinute.Text,
        ddlTimeOutAMPM.Text);

TimeSpan difference = 
    DateTime.Parse(outTime) -
    DateTime.Parse(inTime);
```

And notice you have a "60" in minute dropdowns. You can't to work one hour *and* 60 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I added a button and a handler to calculate the difference. I don't think you can use the CompareValidator. If you need the code as part of validation then I would use a CustomValidator

```
protected void Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim TimeIn As DateTime = CDate(ddlTimeInHour.Text & ":" & ddlTimeInMinute.Text)
        If ddlTimeInAMPM.Text = "PM" Then
            TimeIn = DateAdd(DateInterval.Hour, 12, TimeIn)
        End If

        Dim TimeOut As DateTime = CDate(ddlTimeOutHour.Text & ":" & ddlTimeOutMinute.Text)
        If ddlTimeOutAMPM.Text = "PM" Then
            TimeOut = DateAdd(DateInterval.Hour, 12, TimeOut)
        End If

        Dim DiffMins As Integer = DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute, TimeIn, TimeOut)
        Response.Write("The difference is " & DiffMins & " mins")
    End Sub
```

**C# Equivalent :**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime TimeIn = (System.DateTime)ddlTimeInHour.Text + ":" + ddlTimeInMinute.Text;
    if (ddlTimeInAMPM.Text == "PM") {
        TimeIn = DateAdd(DateInterval.Hour, 12, TimeIn);
    }

    DateTime TimeOut = (System.DateTime)ddlTimeOutHour.Text + ":" + ddlTimeOutMinute.Text;
    if (ddlTimeOutAMPM.Text == "PM") {
        TimeOut = DateAdd(DateInterval.Hour, 12, TimeOut);
    }

    int DiffMins = DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute, TimeIn, TimeOut);
    Response.Write("The difference is " + DiffMins + " mins");
}
```

Comment: @Dilse : You can convert .NET CLR codes to each other with this tool : http://bit.ly/7A7kU9